# Sharing preferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save some values with SharedPreferences in my app. These values constantly change when it is active (for example every game brings some coins, and I want to save these coins). However I don't know when the user will quit the app in order to save the coins then for next time. So in every activity where the coins change I have:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("coins", MainActivity.COINS);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Is there a way to do this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use isFinishing() in onPause() method that means that the application paused and if isFinishing() is true then your app will end

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isFinishing())
    {
        //finishing logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use it in all activities or just one?

Comment: yeah if you don't know where they are going to quit, but isFinishing() in onPause means that they are definetly closing the app